# how to do line break with escape text in JSP

Tags: eclipse, jsp

there is a flag setting in eclipse for 'escape text when pasting into a string literal' in `eclipse` under windows> preferences> java>editor>typing. It does work in `.java` files. But it does not work for `.JSP` files. How to enable this feature for `.JSP` files while using `scriptlet` tags. Like in below code I want to highlight String `abc` in some background color in my `.jsp` file in `eclipse`:

```
<%
String abc="adf";


abc=abc.concat("xyz");
%>
```

Comment: Yet another reason for not using scriplets. :)

Comment: Is not there any way for this... I know scriptlets should NOT be used but still if there is small requirement for scriptlets, then this feature of highlighting should be enabled..